# Modify instead of create object with JAXB

Tags: java, jaxb

Let's say I have class `A` that contains class `B`. Call `A`s constructor creates a `final` instance of `B`, which can be retrieved with the `getB()` method. `B` has it's own internal structure and elements that need to be instantiated by JAXB.

How do I make it so JAXB **modifies `A`'s instance of `B` instead of creating a new `B`**

Example Code:

```
public class A {
   public final B b;

   public void getB() {
      return B;
   }

   public A() {
      this.b = new B()
   }
}

public class B {
    // Elements and things that JAXB needs to save
}
```

Desired XML

```
<A>
   <b>
      [...]
   </b>
</A>
```

Comment: You should return B in getter method

Comment: @Octopus I already am

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the most DRY or really a great solution, but what I came up with was to create a `setB()` method, **but** instead of the method doing something like `this.b = b`, it just copies the necessary properties from `b`, so `this.b.property = b.property`. After that I just put a giant capitalized comment screaming at everyone else not to use the setter unless they're name is JAXB.